# What are the consequences of leveling in lower level areas?

Tags: guild-wars-2

I know guild wars 2 manages to scale (down only) your level acording to the area maximum level.

How will the experience for a level 30 player for instance, leveling on  a level 5-15 area, be calculated ? Will the scalled down level 30 player level up as fast as the lvel 5-15 players in that area ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT** Original information removed as it's now out of date and inaccurate.

**EDIT**: As per january 28th, the [developers made some changes in the way level downscaling works](https://www.guildwars2.com/en-gb/news/dynamic-leveling-adjustment/). According to the article, the net effect is to make downscaling both more challenging /and/ more rewarding.

Comment: It bears mentioning that, normally, the largest proportion of players' xp gains come from hearts, and those don't seem to be affected. As downscaling still leaves you more powerful than usual, hearts are completed faster (especially if you're level 20 or 30 in an 1-15 or 15-25 area that expects you to have one less skill available; the power difference is crazy at those breakpoints). If you aren't too far ahead level-wise, leveling in low areas is -arguably- -faster- (for example as a lvl 20 in 1-15)

Comment: When levelling an Elementalist I found the only way to level was to grind the lower level areas. I've made it to lv30 by using the 1-15 and 15-25 areas. I can't say I found it slow at all.

Comment: Your first point is actually incorrect. I was recently playing on a character around level 25 in Caledon Forest with two level 80 players in my party. Whenever we killed something, they got about 3x as much exp as I did.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is correct. @Brian may be correct. Anyone else ?

Comment: Just tested out the first point. My level 47 Mesmer received 46xp, and in the exact same area, my level 80 Ranger received 198xp (no bonuses, just base xp for killing a firefly).

Comment: With regards to drops, the equipment drops from mobs will be scaled to your level, but chest drops and map completion rewards are "map set", if that makes sense. (Monsters also drop the salvage/trophies relevant to their level and not yours.)

Comment: That said, his general conclusion is more or less correct: levelling in an area below your level will be slower than if it was the same level.

Comment: Since Jan 28th, this has changed, https://www.guildwars2.com/en-gb/news/dynamic-leveling-adjustment/

Comment: As of June 23rd 2015, scaling has been changed, once again. Downscaling reduces your stats even more and upscaling increases your stats more than before.

Answer (score 0):

my experience when playing with my lvl. 15 friend and my level 50 character: I get less money from events and quest than in the higher area. But the drop seems to be balanced to my level and I level up as fast as my friend (approximately). And it's way more fun than playing alone.